# The sum of a specific property of all items in a List

Tags: f#

Take the following example,

I have a class

```
public class SomeItem
{
    public string Name;
    public DateTime Published;
    public uint16 Size;
}
```

I have a `List<SomeItem>` and I want to calculate the total size of all the items.
In C# I'd simply write

```
var totalSize = items.Sum((i) => i.Size);
```

I have taken a look at the List functions in F# but they always complain about the types.

How would you write this in F#?

(I have tried the search engines, but search engine support for F# is terrible)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have a value of type `IEnumerable<Item>`, you can use `sum_by` from the `Seq` module:

```
let totalSize = items |> Seq.sum_by (fun (i : Item) -> i.Size)
```

Note that F#'s `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List<T>` type is not the same class as the one you might be used to from `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, and they're not interchanegable. However, the methods in the `Seq` module work on any `IEnumerable<T>`, and `IEnumerable<T>` is the same between F# and C#.

Comment: You just wrote pretty much word for word what I was writing.  There are too many ninja posters on this site. ;)

Comment: Heh, not sure I'd count myself as a ninja ;). Not sure why this answer got down-voted, though.

Comment: I don't see  why you got downvoted either. Thank you for the answer

Comment: That was my bad, actually. I thought you'd just duplicated my answer, but you've correctly suggested to use Seq.sum_by because it's a System.Collections.Generit.List<T> rather than an F# list (which I didn't realise). Upvoted now. :)

Comment: Thanks guys -- I don't mean to complain about voting; it's just handy to find out if I make a mistake when answering a question.

Answer (score 2):

```
let totalSize = items |> List.sum_by (fun i -> i.Size)
```

LINQ works fine in F# too, but it's probably best to use list comprehension like above, since it's more in the functional tradition (and also performs slightly quicker because it doesn't use `IEnumerable<T>`).

Comment: This assumes you are using an F# `List` by the way (i.e. a linked list), rather than the one in System.Collections.Generic, which you *generally* stay clear of in F# (though F# also has an alias for it called `ResizeArray`).

Comment: Well, the list comes from a c# library so it's the System.Collections.Generic List but you got me going, thnx

Comment: Since I'm doing this on a 'normal' list I used the Seq.sum_by

Comment: No problem. You've got this answer for another situation, anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is "folding" in F# and other functional languages.
Look for examples of Seq.fold.

Comment: The others suggested Seq.sum_by,
I'm interested why you suggest Seq.fold

Comment: @TimothyP: Seq.fold would do the job, just that it's purpose is more generic than sum_by (it could multiple all the values in a list together, for example). sum_by is the nice simple solution in this case.

Comment: Agreed. However, if you're looking for search terms that describe "do stuff to all the items in a sequence and come up with a single result" then searching for fold/folding will give you the general solution.